# state is not updating using React hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This is a function which has to be called when the component mounts on DOM

```
const [dashboardData, setDashboardData] = useState('');

const loadDashboardData = () => {
    console.log("Loading Dashboard Data ", campaign);
    Utils.request({
      url: `campaign/user/info`
    }).then(
      res => {
        console.log("dashboard data" , res.data)
        setDashboardData(res.data);
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    )
  }

 useEffect(() => {

    loadDashboardData();
    console.log("campaigndata",dashboardData);

  }, []);
```

when I console `dashboardData` in `useEffect`, it shows nothing but a string i.e `campaigndata` which I passed as the first argument in `console.log`. what I think that my dashboard state variable is not getting updated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: i am using React hooks, can not pass a callback as second argument

Comment: For hooks, there's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/1218980

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Answer

Write another useEffect just for `dashboardData`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("campaigndata",dashboardData);

}, [dashboardData]);
```

> Explanation

Your `useEffect` is taking an empty array as the second argument, which makes it run only the first time (as DidMount), so it won't re-run on component re-render after changing the state, that's why it is showing empty string as the initial state.
Writing another `useEffect` for the variable `dashboardData` will run as many times as the `dashboardData` changes.

Comment: while initializing state value (with hooks) react passes useState's value to react core, hence during re-renders, data will not be lost if your previous and current state is equal, and if you clean state value manually you should be ready that it will update value in react core (it will be set to empty value) and data will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the 'dashboard' to the existing useEffect as dependency. The existing useEffect will work as both componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate.

> So no need to write another useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
  loadDashboardData();
  console.log("campaigndata",dashboardData);
}, [dashboardData]);
```